# Html Table with 100% width but with growing TD?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table which its width is 100%;

[**I have 2 TDs.**](http://jsbin.com/uneyug/4/edit)

[image]

However I want the second `td` to be near to the `left` end. ( right after the ccccccc...)

[**There is a solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rrkky/1/) which uses 1 more td which its width is 100%.

Something like

```
<table id="mytable"style="width:100%;background:red"><tr>
    <td>TEXT1</td>
    <td>TEXT2</td>
    <td style="width:100%;background:blue">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr></table>
```

But , I was wondering if there's another solution **without** another TD ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Rrkky/144/
Does exactly what you're asking for.

**HTML**

```
<table id="mytable"style="width:100%;background:red">
    <tr>
    <td class="firstcell">aaaa</td>
    <td>TEXT2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="firstcell">bbbbbbb</td>
    <td>TEXT2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="firstcell">ccccccccccccccc</td>
    <td>TEXT2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#mytable td {
    width:50px;
    background:green
}

#mytable td.firstcell {
    background:red;
    width:1%;
}
```

Comment: That's something that comes from your jsFiddle code. I thought you need it. You can remove it as well :)

Comment: This solution has one issue. If other cells (not last with 100%) has text with spaces it will be wrapped even if there is enough space to print it on one line.

Answer (score 3):

What about this ?

```
<table id="mytable"style="width:100%;background:red">
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td width="100%">Royi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bbbbbb</td>
        <td width="100%">Royi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cccccccccccccccc</td>
        <td width="100%">Royi</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS

```
tr td:not(:first-of-type){
    width:100%
}
```

**or**

```
tr td{
    width:100%
}
tr td:first-child{
    width:1%
}
```

Comment: `:not(:` is **not** cross browser (currently) psuedo selector.( also :first-of-type)

Comment: Scope of validation and project platform support are not defined by OP.

Comment: You are absolutely right. however this is nice solution for supported browsers. +1.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Second proposition is crossBrowser-platform ;)

Comment: because you added your .css in a .js input box :: http://jsbin.com/uneyug/16/   ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/rjsAG/

Just do not add the last `TD` but use `width:100%` for the second one